# How can I get the ID of the active Desktop of Mac OS X?

Tags: cocoa, api, desktop, spaces

is there a way to get the ID of the active Desktop in Mac OS X when you have multiple desktops. I didn't find a method or API for that.

Comment: active desktop means?

Comment: Are you talking about the Spaces feature in OS X? Using proper terminology usually helps in Technology....

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the Spaces feature in OS X.

Comment: It's difficult to know, cold, what the proper terminology is. Apple calls them Spaces in some places, Workspaces in others, while Mission Control labels them "Desktop 1", "Desktop 2", etc. So it depends on whether you are coming from the UI side or the API side, which terms you will encounter first.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist` it appears to contain a list of spaces and their windows organized by their window number. Each space has a name (the initial two seem to be dashboard and the empty string, which I assume is the first, default desktop). If you can get a reference to a window number you can attempt to find it in this plist structure to determine which space it is currently in. This may or may not be useful to you depending on what you are trying to do with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HIWindowGetCGWindowID` to get the `CGWindowID` for your `WindowRef`.

Use that ID with `CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray` from `CGWindow.h` to get information on your window.

Look at the returned dictionary and extract the (optional) `kCGWindowWorkspace` key.

**That is your space ID for your window.**

Source: [How to detect which Space the user is on in Mac OS X Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554380/how-to-detect-which-space-the-user-is-on-in-mac-os-x-leopard)

Comment: Thank you. I tried this `-(int)spaceNumber
{
    CFArrayRef windowsInSpace = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionAll | kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);      
    for (NSMutableDictionary *thisWindow in (NSArray *)windowsInSpace)    {
        if ([thisWindow objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowWorkspace]){
            return [[thisWindow objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowWorkspace] intValue];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}` but it doesn't work. It always returns -1. Maybe because `kCGWindowWorkspace` is deprecated in Mac OS X 10.8?

Comment: @user2212391: is there any warning like deprecated ?

Comment: Yes, there is a warning but sometimes deprecated apis still work. But in this case it seems not to work anymore. Is there another way to get the workspace ID?